# GridSplitter располагается под элемнетами формы и становится недоступен

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

Есть окно. На окне следующие элементы (привожу только "шапки", чтобы не засорять текст вопроса ненужным кодом):

```
<Menu Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
...
</Menu>
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
...
</DockPanel>
 <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Width="7"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2">
...
</DockPanel>
<Button x:Name="..." Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"  DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Click="...">
...
</Button>


 <GridSplitter Grid.Column="0"  Grid.Row="3"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Height="2" ResizeDirection="Rows" Margin="10,11" />


<ListView x:Name="..." ItemsSource="..." Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" MaxHeight="250" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" >
...
</ListView>
```

Также выше имеются следующие `RowDefinitions`:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="100"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Проблема следующая: что бы я ни делал, второй GridSplitter (выделенный отступами) располагается поверх шапки `ListView` в конструкторе. А при запуске приложения не видим вообще. Следовательно, своих функций никак не выполняет (от него ожидалась возможность растягивания `ListView` вверх-вниз).

Вопрос: как исправить описанную проблему, чтобы элемент работал корректно и предоставлял возможности растяжения?

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста RowDefinitions и ColumnDefinitions. Сделайте код таким, чтобы можно было воспроизвести проблему, вставив его себе в проект.

Comment: Какая то каша у вас в XAML, структуры вообще как таковой нет. Но да ладно, это уже вас этим жить. Смотрите, в XAML принцип такой - что ниже в коде, то выше в представление. То есть у вас сейчас идет `GridSplitter`, а затем `ListView`, который естественно, перекрывает элемент. Разместите его после `ListView` или укажите `Panel.ZIndex="1"` с индексом, выше чем у `ListView` и будет все отображаться. Работать - не уверен, но отобразится точно.

Comment: @aepot Добавил RowDefinitions. К сожалению, не могу предоставить полностью весь код.

Comment: Спасибо, но легче не стало. Вы можете написать демо пример, в котором данное поведение воспроизводится? Чтобы можно было взять вашу разметку и починить :)